# How to access textblock or UI Element in static class and set the properties

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

How Can I access a textblock or textBox or rectangle box or UI Elements in XAML page from another static class or  a static class helper to do tasks.

I have this problem:
a textBlock in a XAML page:

1) How to access this textblock in a static class to set  Foreground color for textblock or set background Rectangle box or other UI element thru a static Class:

2) How to pass the textBlock to the static class and set it as below

```
textBlock.Foreground = Brushes.Navy;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Binding:

Xaml:

`<TextBlock x:Name="AppStatusValueTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1035,174,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ChangeTextBlockText}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="230"/>`

C#-Class:

```
class YourClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

 private string _changeTextBlockText;

 public string ChangeTextBlockText{
                get
                {
                    return _changeTextBlockText;
                }
                set
                {
                    _changeTextBlockText= value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
        }


 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

 protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
 {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
 }

}
```

EDIT: Example to change the foreground color

Xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockHex" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="90,180,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="hello" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="75" Width="170" Foreground="{Binding TextBlockColorInHex}"/>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public string TextBlockColorInHex
    {
        get
        {
            return _textBlockColorInHex;
        }
        set
        {
            this._textBlockColorInHex = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
       SetColorFromThisClass("#ff0000");
    }

    private void SetColorFromThisClass(string colorInHex)
    {
        TextBlockColorInHex = colorInHex;
    }
    private string _textBlockColorInHex;


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

MainPage.cs:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        ViewModel daViewModel = new ViewModel();
        DataContext = daViewModel;

    }
```

Comment: This binding approach is good.  Can you show me how to change the foreground color of textblock.  I need a rectangle  in xaml which I need to change its background color when certain condition met just like textblock

Comment: I changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Though what you ask is really not a good idea in general it can be done (but again there are much better ways).

So basically you can assign the Dispatcher and TextBox to some field or property in the static class in the page OnNavigatedTo method.

You need to assign both because you can access the TextBox only from UI thread and you can invoke it by Dispatcher.RunAsync method.

EDIT:

```
<TextBox Name="textBox"/>

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    myStaticClass.TextBox = textBox;
    myStaticClass.Dispatcher = Dispatcher;
}
```

Comment: I need to pass the Specific TextBlock to the static class so that I can set the foreground color for the textBlock when it meet certain condition. I can not see what you say. Can you show me how u manipulate this thru a static class. Thanks

Comment: In my Static Class, I can not use the keyword : this     this.TextBlock = _passInTextBlock.

Comment: This is static https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx and my answer works with that. You might be using static word for something else or there might be 'yours' static class but either way you need to provide much more information if you wish to have answer.